# What is the exact behaviour of comparing Integers in Java?

Tags: java

as far as I understand due to Java autoboxing I can do this:

```
Integer i = 10;
Integer j = 10;
boolean b = i == j;
```

Or this:

```
int ii = 10;
int jj = 10;
Integer i = ii;
Integer j = jj;
boolean b = i == j;
```

In both cases b is **TRUE**. 
Then if Integer.parseInt() function returns an int in theory I can do this:

```
Integer i = Integer.parseInt("10");
Integer j = Integer.parseInt("10");
boolean b = i == j;
```

In this case b is also **TRUE**. 
Then if I do this b should be true as well:

```
Integer i = Integer.parseInt("200");
Integer j = Integer.parseInt("200");
boolean b = i == j;
```

Actually here b is **FALSE**. Anyone has an idea of what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: comparing instances and values, educate about `== ` and `equals()`

Comment: always use .equals for wrapper class comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use == between Integers.. It sometimes works only because certain values (I think below 128) are cached by Integer.valueOf() for performance reasons.